# Why do we pass "this" pointer to setupUi function?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm fairly new in QT. Taking below fairly simply explain from qt docs :

```
class CalculatorForm : public QWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
     CalculatorForm(QWidget *parent = 0);
 private slots:
     void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value); //why is that slots are private?
 private:
     Ui::CalculatorForm ui;
 };
```

and implementation of constructor

```
 CalculatorForm::CalculatorForm(QWidget *parent)
     : QWidget(parent) {
     ui.setupUi(this); // <-- Question below
 }
```

Q: I was wondering why do we pass `this` pointer to setupUi function?, what does it do ?

Comment: Did you bother to open generated ui_*.h file and see what exactly happens in generated setupUi method? This gives a lot of answers

Comment: @KamilKlimek yes I did, but the code in that file bothered/baffled me back :P

Comment: Maybe precise your question with parts of ui_*.h file that bothers you most?

Comment: @KamilKlimek can you please explain this para about QSizePolicy : `The size policy of a widget is an expression of its willingness to be resized in various ways` -> various ways? I mean does it means algos to increase the sizes of widgets? or what?

Comment: You should start a new question about QSizePolicy, don't use exisiting question to ask another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that the dialog will have the caller as parent, so that eg when the parent is closed the dialog can be closed automatically. Generally all gui elements have a pointer to their parent.

```
 private slots:
     void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value); //why is that slots are private?
```

These are auto generated slots which exactly match the naming of the gui elments in QtDesigner. They are only meant to do the direct hookup to those gui elements and so should be dealt with in this class. If these signals were extended to other classes then any change in the gui would require changing a lot of other code which doesn't need to know details of the gui.

In the handler slot for the specific gui element you can then emit another more general signal to the rest of the app.

Comment: so a widget (in this case since it inherits from `QWidget` ) can be parent of a QDialog form which holds another widgets? , also does every widgets constructor accepts `QWidget` pointer? Thanks

Comment: Generally every gui element has a parent - yes

Comment: I request you to add some basic example so that I can view what's going on, your answer to my second question (private slots) seems theoritical of which I won't get anything, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only widget that `setupUi` doesn't create is the widget at the top of the hierarchy in the ui file, and as the `Ui::CalculatorForm` class instance doesn't know the widget it has to fill, it (`this`) has to be passed explicitly to the class at some point.

`this` or any other widget you would pass to it, is used as the parent to all other subwidgets. For example, you could fill a widget without inheritance like this:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
Ui::CalculatorForm *ui = new Ui::CalculatorForm;
ui->setupUi(widget);
widget->show();
```

But really, it would be easier to understand if you read the content of the [uic](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html) generated file (probably named `ui_calculatorform.h`).

Answer (score 1):

setupUi creates the instances of widgets (QLabel, QTextEdit and so on). The [user interface compiler] (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html) gets information for you from the .UI form and generates widget-creation code in the generated moc source files.

The manual way of creating widgets without using the Qt Designer or a UI file would be like so:

`QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget(this);`

Comment: Sorry I sort of skirted around your question. What setupUI does is reads the form of the object passed to it and accordingly creates instances. So passing setupUI(this) would read this' UI file and generate code. Is that better or am I still missing your question entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to add the caller widget to the layout of this UI.
This widget will be the toplevel widget.

Martin Beckett answer might be correct as well, as what he described is a common behavior in Qt (cf the 'parent' argument in most of widget's derived class constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have alternative ways how designer can auto-generate code.
In this case you have a separate 'UI' class for this code which is not QObject so it also is not a QWidget.
Auto generated code needs information about parent widget and to make auto-conections of slots and signals so this is why you have to pass `this`.
This pater is less intrusive then other pasterns (that is why it is default). You can also try alternative patters (check Qt Creator Designer options), but I recommend you to see what is generated by designer tools in default settings.

Comment: `In this case you have a separate 'UI' class for this code which is not QObject so it also is not a QWidget` <-  so what if that's the case please? any explanation or explanation would help me better :)

Comment: you have focused on something unimportant. Check what designer is generating (it creates some c++ code) and all should be clear.