# Qt cant open new window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a program that in the main opens a window with user list and 2 buttons, when one button is pressed it should close/hide the main window, and open a new window (in this case MarkdownEditorUi class).

But when I do the .show() comand, the new window does not appear, and I don t know why, int the main (opening the main window works), but in the main window opening a second window does not work.

- I do in the method: FirstCplusPlusQt5Program::buttonMarkdownAction()

  CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi markdownEditor;
    markdownEditor.show();          //show markdown editor window
    this->hide();

But the markdownEditor dont/open show a new window. And i know in the debug that the code is executed.

Am i doing something wrong? It was based in windows created in the Qt Creator. I should work.

Also: when the new window is invoked in the main, it works, and the code is exactly the same. I dont understand why it doesn't work in the main window, but works in the void main();

### Code

#### Main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    RuntimeContainer r(20);
    r.insertLog("Start main","Starting everything ", Log::PROGRAM_STARTUP);

    cout << "Fist log inserted in main memory: \n> Name--> " << r.getLogList().getLogByIndex(0).getName().toStdString() << " \n--> Description: "<< r.getLogList().getLogByIndex(0).getDescription().toStdString();


    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    FirstCplusPlusQt5Program w; 
    w.setRunTimeContainer(r);
    w.show();           //open the main window



    return app.exec();

}
```

#### Main window

[image]

```
    #include "firstcplusplusqt5program.h"
#include "ui_firstcplusplusqt5program.h"

#include <QString>

#include "UC/CreateCategory/UI/createCategoryUi.h"



/**
 * @brief window constructor
 * 
 * @param parent p_parent:...
 */
FirstCplusPlusQt5Program::FirstCplusPlusQt5Program(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::FirstCplusPlusQt5Program){
    ui->setupUi(this);


    //test();

    /**
     *  connection of the button when its pressed with the method "buttonMarkdownAction()"
     **/
    connect(ui->qPushButtonMarkdown, SIGNAL (clicked()),this,SLOT (buttonMarkdownAction()));
    connect(ui->qPushButtonPlantUml, SIGNAL (clicked()),this,SLOT (buttonPlantUmlAction()));

}

/**
 * @brief default destructor
 * 
 */
FirstCplusPlusQt5Program::~FirstCplusPlusQt5Program(){
    delete ui;
}




/**
 *  
 * @brief when button pressed opens markdown editor, is a private slot
 * @details markdown editor is a new window. Validates if user is selected
 */
void FirstCplusPlusQt5Program::buttonMarkdownAction(){
    if (ui->qListWidgetUserList->selectedItems().size() > 0){       //if user list have selected user
        //do things
        QString s = ui->qListWidgetUserList->selectedItems()[0]->text();   //gets selected user name

        if (s.contains(QRegExp(USER_NAME_REGEX_DEFAULT))){      //VALIDATE USER name, database may be currompted
            User userToLogOn = this->r.getUserList().findUser(s);

            cout << "User: " << userToLogOn.getName().toStdString() << " ==> Email " << userToLogOn.getEmail().toStdString() << endl; //FOR TESTING
            CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi markdownEditor;
            markdownEditor.show();          //show markdown editor window
            this->hide();       //hide current window
            cout << "Test";     //FOR TESTING
        }
    }else{
        //error, informs the user from error
        noUserSelected("No user selected!!","Please select user", "No save the notes in differents login locations is needed a user.");

    }
}
```

#### New window to open

> > ### THIS WINDOW OPENS WHEN EXECUTED IN THE MAIN, AND THE CODE IS EXACTLY THE SAME IN THE PREVIEWS CODE

[image]

Cpp

```
#include "createeditmarkdownnoteui.h"
#include "ui_createeditmarkdownnoteui.h"
//#include <QWebEnginePage>

CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi::CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi(QWidget* parent)  : QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi){

    ui->setupUi(this);
}



CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi::~CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi(){
    delete ui;
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef CREATEEDITMARKDOWNNOTEUI_H
#define CREATEEDITMARKDOWNNOTEUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui
{
    class CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi;
}

class CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi(QWidget* parent = 0);

    ~CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi();

private:
    Ui::CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi* ui;
};

#endif // CREATEEDITMARKDOWNNOTEUI_H
```

.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
    <class>CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi</class>
    <widget class="QMainWindow" name="CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi">
        <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>0</y>
                <width>800</width>
                <height>600</height>
            </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="windowTitle">
            <string>CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi</string>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
        <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
            <property name="geometry">
                <rect>
                    <x>0</x>
                    <y>0</y>
                    <width>800</width>
                    <height>23</height>
                </rect>
            </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
    </widget>
    <resources/>
    <connections/>
</ui>
```

#### Cmake list (similar to make, or qmake, with list of cpp files and .ui to run/compile)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(FirstCplusPlusQt5Program)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)


#
#
# @author : josemiguel443@gmail.com = add src file of .cpp of used/compiled 
#classes
#
#
#
set(

  # PROJECT DEPENDENCIES
  firstcplusplusqt5program_SRC
  src/main.cpp
  src/firstcplusplusqt5program.cpp

  # DOMAIN
  src/Domain/Category.cpp
  src/Domain/User/user.cpp
  src/Domain/note.cpp

  #DOMAIN LIST

  src/Domain/List/categorylist.cpp

  # LOG
  src/RuntimeLog/log.cpp
  src/RuntimeLog/loglist.cpp



  # DOMAIN LIST

  src/Domain/List/noteList.cpp
  src/Domain/List/userList.cpp

  # UTILS
  src/Utils/utils.cpp

   # UC
  src/UC/CreateCategory/UI/createCategoryUi.cpp
  src/UC/CreateNoteWithMarkdown/UI/createeditmarkdownnoteui.cpp          #note used yet

  # PERSISTENCE
  src/Persistence/InMemory/runtimecontainer.cpp

)

# Create code from a list of Qt designer ui files.
#set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) # use this if you have CMake 3.x instead of the following
#
#
# @author : josemiguel443@gmail.com = add src file of .ui for QT
#
#
#
qt5_wrap_ui(firstcplusplusqt5program_SRC 
    src/firstcplusplusqt5program.ui
    src/UC/CreateCategory/UI/createCategoryUi.ui
    #src/UC/CreateNoteWithMarkdown/createeditmarkdownnoteui.ui          #note used yet
)






# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(firstcplusplusqt5program ${firstcplusplusqt5program_SRC})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(firstcplusplusqt5program Qt5::Widgets)

# Install the executable
install(TARGETS firstcplusplusqt5program DESTINATION bin)
```

### Output

```
user19User: user5 ==> Email user5@gmail.com
Test
*** Finished ***
```

I already tried the solutions given in another threads of stack overflow and dont work and i dont understand why ([How to open a new window from the main window in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988292/how-to-open-a-new-window-from-the-main-window-in-qt)).

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use:

`ui->setupUi(this);`

If you want your ui-design be set up on a new window, `this` should be this new window. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12182145/4599792 .

I doubt however if it is smart or possible to have two *windows* of **QMainWindow** type within the same application. So let your ui-design run within a **QWidget** *window*, but not within **QMainWindow** *window*.

Comment: I one had an application that could spawn several QMainWindows, never was a problem having more than one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the object is getting out of scope.

In `main` function the window open and stills openned due the event loop `app.exec();`. It's preventing reaches the end of the scope of your main function until the program ends and the event loop returns the exit code.

To work around this problem without too much changes in your code you can create the class with `new`  and get rid of the problems with scope, set a parent to this class to enable auto delete or set explicitly the `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` with the same purpose.

Also remember that if all windows are closed and `QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed() == true;` the entire application will be closed, so if necessary call `QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);` and exit your application explicitly using `QApplication::quit();` for example:

```
CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi *markdownEditor = new CreateEditMarkdownNoteUi(this);
markdownEditor->show();
```

Comment: but in some threads they say that using new in c++ is bad practices.